# Monodroid GenyMotion access internet through code

Tags: android-emulator, xamarin.android, virtualbox

I have struggling for the past week to try to get this to work. I have downloaded this fantastic tool which is the genymotion emulator for android. But I can't access the internet from my line of code.

```
        using( WebClient wbclient = new WebClient() )
        {
            try
            {                    
                String URI = "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"; // test purpose only
                Stream s = wbclient.OpenRead( URI );
                using( StreamReader r = new StreamReader( s ) )
                {
                    string str = r.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
               // handle...
            }
        }
```

This is a simple service that returns the time. If I enter this address in the browser of the guest device genymotion ( android 4.2.2 - API 17 ), the browser works perfectly and the time is returned. But the above code throws an exception "Connection time out". Why within my guest device the above url can be retrieved from the browser and properly display the time and throw an exception when access in code via WebClient object? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not your code: you have discovered that genymotion is not on the internet - this flaw is by *official design*. this happens because genymotion (a wrapper for VirtualBox) dis-disconnects the *correct* adapters (that you may or may not have set in VirtualBox) and uses it's own (faulty) "Host Only Adapter" networking setting instead, and then HIDES that it does this.

To fix this highly unfair "bug" (feature?) you have to go into VirtualBox, find the GenyMotion machine by name and then power it off, right click to "Settings" networking and then click under "adapter 2" (tab) and tick "enable network adapter" then click "attached to:>Bridged Adapter" assuming your pc that you are running it all on runs under DHCP it will set up a IP for the Android VM that GenyMotion proclaims as it's own (which it is not)